# Aclarando las limitaciones de la API de twitter

Tags: twitter-api

Estoy interesado en incluir la nueva API de twitter en mi aplicación Android.
He estado leyendo la documentación y hay algo que no me queda claro con respecto a las limitaciones.

En mi aplicación, con la API incluida, el usuario introducirá su cuenta de twitter para funcionar.

Realmente, son muy pocos los datos que voy a necesitar más allá del nombre de usuario y el número de seguidores, la cifra, no las ido ni nada por el estilo.

La llamada que tendría que usar para ese fin, según la documentación es la de `GET users/show`, la cual tiene una limitación de 900 requerimientos por cada 15 minutos.

Mi pregunta es:
Pongamos que mi aplicación está instalada en 1.000 móviles, esas 900 llamadas son por cada móvil que tenga instalada la aplicación o por la propia aplicación, sumando las llamadas que puedan hacer los 1.000 móviles.

Agradezco cualquier información que me aclare el camino.

Saludos y gracias!